# Calling MySQL Procedure is giving an exception that "procedure cannot be found"

Tags: c#, php, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

During calling procedure from c# it showing the following Error

> "Procedure or function 'CALL `get_Users()'`cannot be foundin database '`joomla`'."`

the code is as follows

```
public ObservableCollection<Users> loadUserData()
        {

            ObservableCollection<Users> UserDetials = new ObservableCollection<Users>();
            Users users;
            using (MySqlConnection Conn = new MySqlConnection(DataBaseConnection))
            {
                Conn.Open();

                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("CALL `get_Users();", Conn);  // uasing this one it showing Error

                // MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("select * from users", Conn); -- if this code run it's taking data from the database

                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                using (var cursor = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (cursor.Read())
                    {
                        users = new Users();
                        users.UserId = Convert.ToInt64(Reader["id"]);
                        users.UserName = Convert.ToString(Reader["Name"]);
                        UserDetials.Add(users);
                    }
                }
            }
            return UserDetials;

        }
```

- image is attached[image]

Comment: What's the use of ` in calling stored procedure?

Comment: if i remove ` this one same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you can call your stored procedure without the CALL keyword and (). Since, you already shoot the command on `System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure`.

So you might try `MySqlCommand("get_Users", Conn)`

Comment: thanks for your valuable information. its work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have a spurious backtick. Use this:

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("CALL get_Users();", Conn);
```

Alternatively you may also have a spurious underscore. In that case use:

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("CALL getUsers();", Conn);
```

It's not clear what `get_Users()` really is. Maybe you should post the definition of it and we'll see what is going on.

Additionally, try executing the command directly from the MySQL admin console by typing:

```
use <database-name>;
CALL get_Users();
```

or

```
use <database-name>;
CALL getUsers();
```

And see what it returns. If it doesn't work from the admin console it probably won't from anywhere else.

Comment: get_Users() , is the procedure name. i used the `Call getUsers()` same issue. in admin console it is working for me.